# Does the .net Reference Assemblies folder have to be on the system drive?

Tags: .net, performance, assemblies

While looking at issues with build times in Visual Studio, I see using System Monitor that it is reading a lot of files form the  .net Reference Assemblies folder.

The .net Reference Assemblies folder is on the system drive that is a normal drive; however we have a SSD in each machine.    So can I move it to the SSD?

Comment: You could move those files to the SSD and create a junction point from the original directory to the new one (with `mklink` or similar)

Comment: FWIW you would probably see a noticeable improvement across the board by making the SSD the system drive (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, I prefer Tim Medora's approach because it's cleaner and will give you a big boost overall.  I just got an SSD in my work laptop and it is absolutely fantastic.

However, yes, I think you can probably copy the reference assemblies off the system drive if you really wanted to.  I don't think it's supported by Microsoft, but I think it would work.

I was doing some digging in Microsoft.Common.targets after reading that ResolveAssemblyReference was the task most closely related to that reference assembly folder.

I then found this (I was specifically looking at 3.5, x64 version):

```
<!--
============================================================
                                    GetReferenceAssemblyPaths

Get the paths for the Reference Assemblies for the known versions of the
.NET Framework.

These paths are used by the build process in order to resolve the correct
assemblies from the various directories, and to support multi-targeting
============================================================
-->
<PropertyGroup>
    <GetReferenceAssemblyPathsDependsOn></GetReferenceAssemblyPathsDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target
    Name="GetReferenceAssemblyPaths"
    DependsOnTargets="$(GetReferenceAssemblyPathsDependsOn)">

    <!-- Ordering of target framework directories doesn't matter except for assemblies
         that aren't in a redist list; for those, make sure we order 3.5, 3.0, 2.0 -->

    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v3.0' or '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v3.5' ">        
        <TargetFrameworkDirectory>$(WinFXAssemblyDirectory);$(TargetFrameworkDirectory)</TargetFrameworkDirectory>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v3.5' ">        
        <TargetFrameworkDirectory>$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders\v3.5@All Assemblies In);$(TargetFrameworkDirectory)</TargetFrameworkDirectory>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Target>
```

Note the registry location for the TargetFrameworkDirectory property - sure enough, it points to that reference assembly folder.

There are 3 options I can see - there may be others:

1. Change the appropriate .targets file for the version of .NET and hard-code a system path
2. Change the registry entry (this might cause nasty side effects)
3. Attempt to override the value of TargetFrameworkDirectory at build time using MSBuild

Curious to see if this works for you!